# How to force View to update bound properties in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I would like to force an databound property update in a content page. In this case is the `ContentPage` `Title` parameter.

```
<ContentPage x:Class="Containers.Views.ContainerPage" 
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         Title="{Binding SomeStringProperty}"
         Appearing="ContentPage_Appearing">
```

The closest i get is this, but it does not works.

```
    private void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindingContext = null;
        this.BindingContext = myClassInstance;
    }
```

I would not like to implement `onPropertyChange` events. I Just want to "refresh" the bounded data of a view.

Comment: does your BindingContext class implement INotiftyPropertyChanged?

Comment: yes it does inherit `BaseDataObject` that inherit from `ObservableObject` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`;

Comment: But i would like to DO NOT implement on event changes properties.

Comment: well, that's the correct solution for updating databound properties - fire a PropertyChanged event.  If you don't want to write all that boilerplate code, use the Fody package instead.

Comment: why don't you want to use INofifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your viewmodel already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` - you can try raising PropertyChangedEvent with null/empty parameter - that should force an update for all bound properties - [more details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx#Remarks).

```
public void RaiseAllProperties()
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
}
```

Comment: LIMITATION: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if making a subclass of BindableObject (so that BindableObject handles some details of INotifyPropertyChanged). Get compiler error "The event BindableObject.PropertyChanged can only appear on the left-hand side of += or -=.". However it is useful to know, if rolling one's own INotifyPropertyChanged implementor.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve do you have a solution for this?
I am currently stuck with this problem.

Comment: @JonathanPeel - No. The more I used Data Binding, the more I ran into complex situations that it does not handle well (or that were very difficult to debug). When I get a chance, I'm going to investigate MVU in Maui. Hoping that is a more straightforward way to coordinate view and model.

Comment: To mention funny times when the page is in shell, is hidden (in other tab or below other pages) and its renderer is disposed "for performance reasons" to be recreated after the page is coming on top, well at those times of unavailable renderer the page will not update its bindings at all. To create a surprise to customer and developer when that page finally appears will totally old values..

Comment: This answer (and the linked MSDN article) seems misleading. Calling `NotifyPropertyChanged` with a null/empty `propertyName` parameter simply calls the handler you've assigned to the `PropertyChanged` event, so it falls back on the developer to update any views accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A way that worked for me with CustomView is:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Xam.CustomViews.ContentsViews
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FeatherButton : ContentView
    {
        // ... Existing code ...

        public FeatherButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == StyleProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateVisualProperties();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateVisualProperties()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextColor));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundColor));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderColor));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderWidth));
        }

        // ... Existing code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanPeel, this may work for you